# Is the Tensor Product Space Isomorphic to One of its Factors if They Are Infinite Dimensional?

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two *infinite* dimensional vector spacees and let $X_1 \otimes X_2$ be their tensor product space. My question is, is it possible to construct an isomorphism between $X_1 \otimes X_2$ and one of its facots $X_1$ or $X_2$ such that we have
$$
X_1 \cong X_1 \otimes X_2 \hspace{1cm} \text{or} \hspace{1cm} X_2 \cong X_1 \otimes X_2
$$
Don't mention something like $\mathbb{R} \otimes \mathbb{R}  \cong \mathbb{R} $ which is *one* dimensional and very trivial case that has nothing to do with the question here. I think if $X_1 = X_2 = c_{00}$, i.e. the  set of all sequences of only finitely many elements different from zero, then is possible to have
$$
c_{00} \cong  c_{00}\otimes  c_{00} \tag{*}
$$
by some mapping between basis in $c_{00}$ and the product basis in $ c_{00}\otimes  c_{00}$. Then for every bilinear map $\phi$ on $ c_{00} \times c_{00}$ there is a linear map $\tilde\phi$ on $ c_{00}$. But that is true only if (*) is true, so is it in general the case for the tensor product of *infinite* dimensional spaces ? and so is it a direct utilization of the linearisation of the bilinear maps ?

Another question is, if I chose $\ell^2 \otimes \ell^p$ spaces would
$$
\ell^p \cong \ell^p \otimes \ell^p 
$$
be true ? I think not.

Comment: You know that $\dim(V\otimes W)=\dim(V)\dim(W)$?

Comment: If $X_1$ is over $\Bbb{R}$ and $X_2$ is over $\Bbb{F}_2$ then the tensor product is $0$.

Comment: The examples you mention are topological vector spaces so it's unclear whether you're considering one of various possible topological tensor products and asking for topological isomorphisms. A bare infinite-dimensional vector space is determined up to isomorphism by its dimension, and it's certainly possible for $X_1, X_2, X_1 \otimes X_2$ to all have the same dimension. A similar result is true for Hilbert spaces and the Hilbert space tensor product, with "dimension" replaced by the cardinality of an orthonormal basis.

Comment: @JCAA OK, you mentioned sth more trivial than $\mathbb{R} \otimes \mathbb{R}  \cong \mathbb{R}$ , I should have said that the spaces $X_1$ and $X_2$ are both over the same field

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I don't mean in the question any topological vector spaces. you thought that because I mentioned the $\ell^p $ spaces. but we if considered this space without its inner product structure (and therefore without its topology), can we find an isomrphism $\ell^p \cong \ell^p \otimes \ell^p$ ?

Comment: Yes. Both sides have the same dimension (the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, sorry but how do you determine the dimensions, what bases do $\ell^p$ have, the same as $c_{00}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$c_{00}$ has countable dimension, so using the fact that the dimension of a tensor product is the product of the dimensions (which continues to hold in infinite dimensions) and that $|\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}| = |\mathbb{N}|$ we get an abstract isomorphism $c_{00} \cong c_{00} \otimes c_{00}$, unconditionally.

Assuming the axiom of choice, [Hamel bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)#Analysis) always exist (this is in fact equivalent to AC), which means infinite-dimensional vector spaces have dimensions. Then we can show that $\ell^p$ has dimension the [cardinality of the continuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_the_continuum) $|\mathbb{R}|$, which squares to itself, so again we get an abstract isomorphism $\ell^p \otimes \ell^p \cong \ell^p$.

The dimension can be computed as follows. $\ell^p$ itself has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$ (exercise), so $|\mathbb{R}|$ is an upper bound on its dimension. To give a lower bound it suffices to exhibit an $\mathbb{R}$'s worth of linearly independent elements of $\ell^p$. Explicitly if we work in $\ell^p(\mathbb{N})$ we can take

$$v_r(n) = e^{-rn}, r \in \mathbb{R}_{+}.$$

It's a nice exercise to prove that these sequences are linearly independent.

There is also a general argument using the Baire category theorem to show that an infinite-dimensional Banach space can't be countable-dimensional, but it doesn't follow that the dimension is at least $|\mathbb{R}|$ without the continuum hypothesis.